# Jquery map won't retrieve selected options; always empty? Appears to skip variable, Works on jsfiddle, No console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, multi-select

**SOLVED:**

Final fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AcfUz/220/

*used the selector indicated in the chosen answer and moved the console.log value ahead of the text input the selected options were to be listed in and boom--working as it should!

Please reference this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AcfUz/218/

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#go', function() {
    console.log("woo");
    var selMulti = jQuery.map(jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select :selected"), function(e) {
        return jQuery(e).val();
        console.log("hoo");
    });
    //var selMulti = jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select :selected").val();
    console.log(selMulti + "hmm...");
    console.log("hootie");
    //jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation").val(selMulti.join(", "));
    jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation").val(selMulti);
    console.log("who");
});
```

This works perfectly on fiddle but no matter how many iterations I try it won't work on the live site. The variable containing the desired values is always empty. I can't for the life of me figure out why?????

Can anyone shed some light in my hour of desperation? It's been 7 hours and I need to solve this before the morning.

I suppose to expand on this--the code in the fiddle is the code I include in the site. The form and then the script before the closing body tag. The form is dynamically loaded (takes about a second). What I need to accomplish is grabbing whatever values a user selects from any of the multi select fields (I'm starting with the one) and copy those as a comma separated list into another single line text input. The fiddle works splendidly, but I'm coming up empty on the live site. I just returns blank/empty--it doesn't give me any console errors what so ever (save for a missing img) and I can see my console.log checkpoints.

Here is the live link:

http://goo.gl/ll1Hz4

Comment: you gotta paste the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AcfUz/218/

Comment: I apologize for the poor formatting; it's been a long night

Comment: mind pasting link to live site for comparison?

Comment: If it works in fiddle and not on live site, my first guess would be that the script is breaking due to previous code execution on the live site.  So def check console for errors on live.

Comment: Here is the live link: http://goo.gl/ll1Hz4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89130/discussion-between-flcoder-and-deez717).

Comment: there is some error in you live link , can you fix it first

Comment: You are not using map in fiddle, where as you have jquery map in your live code... could you please verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the live website if I try `$("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select option")` in the console, the options are listed twice. Using `$('select')` 2 `#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select` are returned. (although I didn't see 2 instances in the page source) (`$("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select");` returns one, but that uses getElementbyID and skips the search). Perhaps the second select is created by some sort of overlay?

All in all, I didn't search any further where the 2nd select come from. A quick fix would be to use a selector searching the attribute. The following selector worked while testing on the live site:

```
$("select[id=inf_custom_Choosealocation_select] :selected")
```

But that might be only a temporary work around. You'll probably want to find the ghost select culprit too ;)

Comment: Hazza! That did indeed pull the selected values! Working on the secondary copy...

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: I appreciate the input; this did not seem to have any affect

Answer (score 0):

You are not using jQuery map in fiddle, where as you have jquery map in your live code...

**Try to update your live site with the code you have in fiddle.**

**Live Code:** (has jQuery map)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I double checked. The code  that is in the fiddle is the code being called on the live version as well. I can't tell what is breaking it.

Comment: I am afraid, it is not. I can see that in your live site, in the html page with title " Step 6 | Australia Work Pack", at the end, you have the "go" button click event and the code is different than you have provided in fiddler. The above screenshot is taken from your live website.

Comment: I appreciate the diligence; I'll check again-my apologies.

Comment: No worries. Let me know your findings in Live website.

Answer (score 0):

So, yeah, I am not sure why :selected isn't working in your case, but you can try to go through the options and check manually... `jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select option").each(function(i, o){ console.log(o.selected) })`

Comment: The live problem has to do with jQuery not matching :selected options because jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select :selected") results in nothing.  But I am not sure why this is the case on live.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
var selMulti = jQuery.map(jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select :selected"), function(e) {
    return jQuery(e).val();
    console.log("hoo");
});
```

use

```
var selMulti=jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select").val();
```

Comment: Doesn't work... go to live site and put in console: jQuery("#inf_custom_Choosealocation_select").val();, you get null.  I'm guessing something is breaking options being :selected and I'm guessing .val() on selects relies on them being :selected.